# Cannot access GeoServer on http://localhost:8080/geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I'm getting error 503 not found for localhost:8080/geoserver/web I downloaded GeoServer version 2.13.2 and pointed the JRE to here: C:\Program Files\Java\jre10.0.1

Comment: Geoserver won't work with java 10, try with java8

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer does not work on Java 10, please remove it and install Java 8 instead. The first release planned to run on higher versions of Java (in particular Java 11) is scheduled for early 2019.